# Why do I get this syntax error in my code generating program?

Tags: perl, dynamic, code-generation, compiler-errors, perl-io

I want to generate some lines of Perl code by using file handling in Perl, for example:

```
open(FILEHANDLE, ">ex.pl") or die "cannot open file for reading: $!";
print FILEHANDLE "use LWP::UserAgent;"
....
.... some code is here 
....
print FILEHANDLE "my \$ua = new LWP::UserAgent(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.5) Gecko/20060719 Firefox/1.5.0.5');"
```

But when I compile the generator code (not the generated) I get this error:

```
syntax error at F:\test\sys.pl line 14, near "print"
Execution of F:\test\sys.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

What am I going to do?

Comment: The first line is contradictory: you open for writing, but the error message says "reading", which is misleading.

Comment: @Svante: copy-and-paste.. the source of 54.8% of all bugs in the universe.

Comment: Why are you writing code that generates code?  That's an unusual thing to do, particularly in a basic script.

Comment: Not easy to see due to the long lines: in the question it is **Firefox/1.5.0.5');"** ---- In DVK's answer it is **Firefox/1.5.0.5')";**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the closing `' " '` (double quote) at the end of the last print's string (before semicolon).

Should be:

```
print FILEHANDLE "my \$ua = new LWP::UserAgent(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.5) Gecko/20060719 Firefox/1.5.0.5')";

... Firefox/1.5.0.5')"; # To show end of that line without scrolling
```

Also, couple of minor notes:

- Please consider using [3-argument form](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) of `open()`, not 2-argument; as well as lexical filehandles:

  open(my $fh, '>', "out.txt") or die "Error opening for writing: $!";
  print $fh "stuff\n";
- You don't have a `close()` of the filehandle at the end - I assume just because you gave incomplete code.

Comment: yes but when i put " at the end of last print i get this error again .
I edit it

Comment: @Jessica: Did you put it before ':' as in the example in the answer?

Comment: @Jessica - nothing to be sorry about,my wording was't as clear as it shoulda been (this the actual code example :)

Did it work now?

Comment: @Jessica - LOL... I'm gonna have to pass on the kiss upon the threat of bodily harm from Mrs. DVK, but "accepting" this answer by clicking on a checkmark next to it and/or up-voting it by clicking on an up-arrow next to it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon on the end of this line:

```
print FILEHANDLE "use LWP::UserAgent;"
```

Comment: original version of the question had the semicolon but not the closing quote... the one out there right now is an updated one

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'd write it in modern Perl:

```
use autodie qw(:all);
{
    open my $handle, '>', 'ex.pl';
    print {$handle} <<'PERL_SOURCE';
use LWP::UserAgent;
…
#  ↓ no variable quoting necessary thanks to here-document
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.5) Gecko/20060719 Firefox/1.5.0.5');
…
PERL_SOURCE
}
```

As Ether hinted at in comments at the top, it's almost never necessary to write out dynamically generated code into a file. [`eval`](http://p3rl.org/eval) and [`Moose::Meta::*`](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Moose::Meta::) exist for a reason.